# Finding channel id and object by name discord.py 0.16.12

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that was made for a single server, therefore, having all channels and roles be found by id but since we starting a server network I need to rewrite somethings to make it be able to work on other servers and the best way I can think of doing this is getting `channel object` by name from `server object`

one way I found to do this is:

```
server = bot.get_server(member.server)
for channel in server.channels:
    if channel.name == "Channel name":
        break
```

and while it does the job I find it pretty ineffective and mostly slow. so any other methods/code will be greatly appreciated.

thank you in advance

Comment: 0.16.12 hasn't been updated for years and you should migrate to the latest version. The discord API has changed a bit and some of the functionalities in 0.16.12 are broken and won't be fixed. For your use case it may be working but it will cause you a lot of headache down the road.

Comment: I was going to but after I found out it was full rewrite and everything changed I just decided to stay with 0.16.12 since its the one I'm most familiar with and I haven't really gone into any problems let alone big ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get by using the `discord.utils.get` *(V1.0.0 or newer)*

```
server = bot.get_server(member.server)
channel = discord.utils.get(server.text_channels, name='Channel name')
```

[Link to Doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20channel#discord.utils.get)

Comment: Your doc link is pointing towards latest discord.py version. OP specifically asked for 0.16.12 which has a lot of breaking changes to >=1.0.0

Comment: I also already tried that and found that it doesn't work for telling the bot to send a message in that channel